# Automatic bluetooth pairing on button click

Tags: android

I have a problem that I want to do an automatic Bluetooth pairing on button click in android.
But I doesn't have any reference to do the same. Please suggest me any solution for the same.
After the pairing I have to transfer an Image. I don't know how it would be done? Please suggest If you have any suggestion regarding this also. But the first priority is to Automatic pairing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the system will allow you to pair automatically the first time. As far as I know there must be user interaction in order to turn on the bluetooth radio, and to pair (but not to "connect" to) a device. Check out the Bluetooth chat example on the dev site to get started. http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BluetoothChat/index.html